# Longitudinal studies on: how attention to emotional stimuli develops from infancy to childhood?

Tags: brain, cognitive-science, psychologist-psychology

According to LeDoux’s model (1996) we have specialized pathways for processing emotional cues. Pourtois, Schettino and Vuilleumier (2013) offer a neural model of how emotional signals capture attention. In their model, amygdala is not only able to respond to relevant cues, it also have a role in *orienting attention* towards **emotional stimuli** (with the assistance of other brain areas).

In other words, human beings don’t attend emotional stimuli in the same way they attend other objects.

**Are there any experimental data explaining how this preference for emotional stimuli develops from infancy to childhood?**

[My reference: Pourtois et al 2013 "Brain mechanisms for emotional influences on perception and attention: what is magic and what is not."](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22373657)

Comment: Great q that would better be served in CogSci

Comment: @DoctorWhom I asked some cogsci mods if this would be on topic there. If it is, I will migrate it.